# Center bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used this code to create 4 columns in *Bootstrap*

```
<div id="col" class="container-fluid row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <center>
      <h4>Our Story</h4><img src="box.png" />
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Our Story</h4><img src="box.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Our Story</h4><img src="box.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Our Story</h4><img src="box.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

now these columns are aligned horizontally on desktop screen but when I open in mobile then all columns gets align vertically on the left side so I want to make them align center, how can I achieve that?

Comment: change *`class="col-md-3"`* to *`class="col-md-3 text-center"`*

Answer (score 5):

This is so wrong in many ways:

- don't use `center` tag it is deprecated, use `.text-center` from bootstrap instead
- `.row` must be child of `.container`
- if you need to style for mobile you have to use class `xs`

See more info about [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/)

---

Because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve in your mobile view here 2 snippets:

### Snippet #1 - 4 columns horizontal all devices

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="col" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <h4>Our Story</h4>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Snippet #2 - 4 columns vertical mobile / 4 columns horizontal small devices and up

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="col" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <h4>Our Story</h4>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Our Story</h4>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```